# How to Get a list of job source code management and build for all jobs

Tags: jenkins, build

[image]I am looking for a way to get a list of build and source code management section in the configuration.

For Example:  I have jobs with Testcomplete and SoupUI Pro plug ins, in each jobs, in the configuration section, we input the git repo name, testsuite name, directory etc ...

Currently, I am having to go to each job, click on configuration and get the values  I need, would be nice where I can get all this information for all the jobs.  I looked in  configuration slicing, but it does not have the section I need.

Thank you for your help in advance.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using groovy script to pull info?

Comment: @IanW no i haven't... not too experienced in Groovy, do you have sample that I can build off of ? thanks also added the image of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used either plugin you mention, but this crude little groovy script will find every Freestyle job and if it has a gitSCM step, report the primary Git repo url, then for every "**Invoke top-level Maven target"**, report the POM value if set.

Run from `<JENKINS_URL>/script` or in a Jenkins job with an "**Execute System Groovy Script**"  (not an "Execute Groovy script").

You can modify to find your plugin's builder step and properties. You can get the values by examining `<job>/config.xml` instead of `<job>/configure`.

**Updated** example to specifically include also looking up [TestComplete](https://plugins.jenkins.io/TestComplete/) plugin ([`com.smartbear.jenkins.plugins.testcomplete.TcTestBuilder`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/TestComplete/com/smartbear/jenkins/plugins/testcomplete/TcTestBuilder.BuildStepAction.html)) values.
Similar approach left to OP for [ReadyAPI Functional Testing](https://plugins.jenkins.io/soapui-pro-functional-testing/) plugin - ([`com.smartbear.ready.jenkins.JenkinsSoapUIProTestRunner`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/soapui-pro-functional-testing/com/smartbear/ready/jenkins/JenkinsSoapUIProTestRunner.html))

**WARNING:* **soapui-pro-functional-testing:1.6** transmits passwords in clear text. So too does SmartBear's Zephyr products. Does not inspire confidence in a company who's tagline is "quality matters more than ever.... we'll help you get there."*

```
Jenkins.instance.allItems.findAll() {
  it instanceof hudson.model.FreeStyleProject
}.each { job ->
  if (job.scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM) {
    println job.fullName + ' | ' + job.scm.userRemoteConfigs.url[0]
    job.builders.findAll() {
      it instanceof hudson.tasks.Maven
    }.each {step ->
      println '   : ' + step?.pom
    }
    job.builders.findAll() {
      it instanceof com.smartbear.jenkins.plugins.testcomplete.TcTestBuilder
    }.each {step ->
      if (step?.getLaunchType() == 'lcRoutine') {
        println '   : ' + step?.getProject() + ' : ' + step?.getUnit() + ' : ' + step?.getRoutine()
      }
    }
  } 
}
return
```

ps: I'm sure there's a cleaner way to iterate but I can't do all the work. Be sure to use the "?" to handle null values

Comment: thank you @IanW - ..  I tried few ways to add the part I want but getting an error.  I added another image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je9h7.png     I added  : job.builders.com.smartbear.jenkins.plugins.testcomplete.TcTestBuildersuite.unit[0]     but no luck ..

Comment: @Mochi79, Updated code. It gets complicated based on what options you choose for **TestComplete** plugin. Pls consider Ipvote and "Answered" as the sol'n is sufficiently complete. Note, the depends on the outer check of a GitSCM, which may not be necessary since that's in the SCM section, not the build step section, but you said "git repo", so it's there.

Comment: - This worked PERFECTLY!!  Thanks again for the help!!!